# ionic serve working for first time, but no further. Getting blank screen from next time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, ionic-native

I am cloning an ionic 5 project from repo. After clone, after changing to the project folder, i did **npm install**, then i did **ionic serve** to run the project in browser. My project runs well. Then, i stopped the ionic serve, and served again, but, this time I am getting blank screen with an error. Below is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:30235)
    at core.js:30253
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:30249)
    at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:30387)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:34669)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:34966)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object.0 (zone-flags.ts:5)
```

**I tried cloning three times in differnt folders, every time ionic serve works for the first time, but no further.**. It is embarassing.

Here is my ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.7
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.7.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : not available
   Cordova Plugins   : not available

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.2 (update available: 0.15.3)
   native-run  : 0.2.8 (update available: 1.3.0)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk)
   NodeJS            : v14.13.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.14.8
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove `node_modules` folder and run npm i

Comment: I did the same also. I am cloning a repo and after this, i just run npm install. and then, ionic serve. It works well for first time. But, after stopping and then again doing ionic serve is giving the error

Comment: Set `NodeJS : v10.16.3` and try